# Alter ReSharper "Complete Statement" behavior

Tags: c#, resharper

I find I am consistently fighting with ReSharper's Complete Statement (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) behavior and I wonder if there is a way to customize it.

What happens is that I will be editing some code, for example:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
```

And then I want to add this to it:

```
var a = 0;
using (var frob = new Thingy())
{
    a = frob.Foo();
}
var b = 1;
```

If I don't use the "using" live template, and just type it in, I hit Complete Statement after typing thingy, and Resharper will copmlete it to this:

```
var a = 0;
using (var frob = new Thingy())
    var b = 1;
```

So, I wonder, is there a way to tell it to always create new braces rather than trying to insert the next line into whatever statement you are adding?

This is using ReSharper 8.1. I've been using it since version 4 and this feels like a new problem, so perhaps they have altered the default behavior.

UPDATE:
Given Thomas Weller's answer, and @Resharper's response on Twitter, I did some more investigating.

There seems to be a discrepancy here. If you look at the docs for [Complete Statement](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Complete_Statement.html) it clearly states:

> With Complete Statement, instead of this tricky procedure, you only
>   have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, and ReSharper will automatically
>   insert a closing parenthesis, **as well as both braces**, and put the
>   caret right where you can proceed with writing the method body
>   In similar ways, Complete Statement is known to work with the
>   following language constructs:
>
> [...]
>   Statements: if, while, do, switch, **using**,
>   lock, continue, break, and return statements; case and default
>   clauses; conversion of single-line statements to block statements.

In testing this out some, I noticed that the behavior for an `if` statement is as expected (it adds the braces and places the carat on a new line inside).  So does `switch` and `checked`.

On the other hand, `while`, `using`, and `fixed` behave as in my example above, where it co-opts the next line of code to be used instead of a new block.

This seems rather inconsistent. Either the docs should be updated, or the behavior should be the same for all statement types.

So, it seems this is more appropriate as a bug report than an SO question. Here is the [link to the bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-401429) if anyone is interested in upvoting it. :)

Comment: I second that it's more of a bug if R# behaves inconsistently.

Comment: As to documentation, I believe it was me who wrote that piece of documentation and I might have been too optimistic about the scope of Complete Statement applicability (or there might have been an unnoticed regression since v4, which kind of speaks volumes to the level of usage of Complete Statement with `using`). Anyway, Rob, thanks a lot for reporting it. As Complete Statement is not currently actively developed, chances are that the request is going to be waiting for a long time to be implemented. Clearly, updating the reference documentation is the easier path to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using R#'s 'Complete Statement' feature as intended, so the tool cannot exactly figure out what you want to achieve.

Complete the `using` statement with the Live template as soon as the template becomes available in IntelliSense, then it will give you the brackets. The Live template will then lead you through typing in the various parts of the statement by highlighting/setting the cursor at the appropriate parts one after the other (don't worry, you won't need to touch the mouse).

Alternatively, Live templates are always accessible and editable via the Live templates explorer (Live templates are similar to 'normal' code templates). But I would not recommend that for predefined ones, unless you have a strong reason to do so.

Comment: Using Complete Statement in this case is just completely redundant.

Comment: I mean that [Complete Statement](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Complete_Statement.html) is not applicable in this case, it's pure live template deployment as you described.

Comment: @gorohoroh In what case? And why would it not be applicable? And what gets 'deployed'? To where?

Comment: See my updates - I'd contest the assertion that I am not using it as intended, given the referenced documentation.

Comment: @RobH Clearly, you're right when talking about the reference documentation. I've seen that only now, and I was slightly surprised that it suggests a usage which is different from mine (I'm using R# for ages and I can't say anymore where I came up with that information). Apart from that: Does it work when doing it as I suggested?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, it does. However, I've known about doing it that way - it just isn't my go-to. I think that I typically use Complete Statement for if's and similar 'simple' statements, and use the Live Templates for the more complex ones such as for and foreach. Like you - I've also used R# for ages and that's why I'm a little baffled by this. :)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Either I'm desperately incomprehensible or you're deliberately inapprehensive. _In what case_: in the case described by the asker. _Why would it not be applicable_: because in my understanding there's no need to use Complete Statement if there's a live template for `using` that is suggested in the completion list. _What gets 'deployed'?_ The live template. _To where?_ To your code editor.

Comment: @gorohoroh Ahh. Looks like I'm inapprehensive. I didn't even consider the asker's question that way because it's only a pointless example for illustration purposes anyway. So all the other points also don't really apply -;)...